# After Interval wait for song to end in iframe audio player before running function in parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, setinterval, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a local html audio player that shuffles between pages that have multiple audio players. I want the shuffle to happen every 30 mins but I want it to wait until the first audio player is done playing it's track before running the random play function.

I am having trouble with getting the main window to access the audio player in the iframe and I also am confused about how to call an eventlistener within a setinterval command.
Here is my code:

Main Page:

```
<iframe src="sPLIF.html" height="200" width="900" frameborder="0" id="pmframe" title="PLIF Player"></iframe>

<script>
    var lastSong = null;
    var selection = null;
    var playlist = [
    "PLIF1/plif1.html", 
    "PLIF200703/PLIF200703.html",
    "PLIF200802/PLIF200802.html",
    "PLIF200808/PLIF200808.html",
    "PLIF200816/PLIF200816.html",
    "PLIF200823/PLIF200823.html",  
    "PLIF_Noir/PLIF_Noir.html",
    "PLIF3_Dream/plif3_dream.html", 
    "sPLIF.html"]; 
   
    var player = document.getElementById("pmframe");
    function selectRandom(){
        while(selection == lastSong){
        selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
    }
        lastSong = selection; 
        player.src = playlist[selection]; 

    }
    
    selectRandom(); 
    setInterval(endSong, 1800000); 

var alto = document.getElementById("pmframe").contentWindow.player;
  
setTimeout(endSong, 1800000); 

function endSong(){
    alto.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom);
}
    
</script>
```

and one example iframe page:

```
<audio id="alto" autoplay>
<source src="alto.m4a" type="audio/m4a">
</audio>

<audio id="drums" autoplay>
<source src="drums.m4a" type="audio/m4a">
</audio>



<script>
    var lastSong = null;
    var selection = null;
    var playlist = [
    "alto1x.m4a", 
    "alto1x.m4a",    
    "pause.m4a"]; 
    var player = document.getElementById("alto"); 
    player.autoplay=true;
    player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom);

    function selectRandom(){
        selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
        lastSong = selection; 
        player.src = playlist[selection]; 
    }

    selectRandom(); 
    player.play(); 
</script>

<script>
    var lastSong2 = null;
    var selection2 = null;
    var playlist2 = ["drums1x.m4a", "drums1x.m4a", "pause30s.m4a"]; 
    var player2 = document.getElementById("drums"); 
    player2.autoplay=true;
    player2.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom2); 

    function selectRandom2(){
        selection2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist2.length);
        lastSong2 = selection2; 
        player2.src = playlist2[selection2]; 
    }

    selectRandom2(); 
    player2.play(); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for posting code - that is usually helpful. You don't in this case really say why this code isn't sufficient, what you have tried and doesn't work or the exact behaviour that isn't what you're looking for. Please edit your question and add more details so people can help you find an answer!

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche ok thank you for your help, I have updated the listing. Basically I am having trouble getting the "document.getElementById("pmframe").contentWindow.player;" to communicate with the audio player in the iframe. I have tried simple pause tests and it doesn't seem to be syncing. But also I'm not sure if my setInterval with an event listener to play a function is setup properly.